# PgAdmin4 Reverse Proxy with Nginx redirects back to Home Page instead of pgAdmin4 browser?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, pgadmin, nginx-location, pgadmin-4

I am experiencing a rather bizarre issue whereby if I am logged out of pgadmin4 and try to login I am redirected to the home page of my site instead of the pgadmin4 browser. This only occurs when the URL is `/pgadmin4/login?next=%2Fpgadmin4%2F` and I try and login. I am looking at my Nginx config and cannot see what is the problem. Navigating to `/pgadmin4/` after having logged in works fine so the issue is somewhere in `login?next=%2Fpgadmin4%2F`, whereby it logs me in but then redirects back to `/` instead of `/pgadmin4`.

```
location /pgadmin4 {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;  
}
```